# Extract residuals from heteroskedasticity robust standard model

Tags: r, linear-regression

I need to extract residuals from a model in R where I have used `coeftest(OLS,vcov=hccm(OLS))`. Does anybody know how to do it, please?

The use of `residuals()` or `resid()` don't work with this function though it works with `lm()`.

Comment: There are only the residuals from the OLS model. It appears, you don't know what `coeftest` does (hint: it doesn't fit a regression model, hence there are no residuals).

Answer (score 0):

As @Roland pointed out, the function `coeftest`does not produce an object with residuals because it is not a model. It is a test of a model, so there are no residuals to extract.

You can use `resid()` on the OLS model which should work.

Comment: I've seen that it's a function allowing to correct for heteroskedasticity. And so I've believed that its results give the estimators with the correct significance, and so that the residuals of the orignal OLS might have been corrected during the process. However if I've well understand your message, the residuals don't change. Is is right ? Thank you

Comment: @Barry the function gives you confidence intervals based on the coefficient test, these intervals are around the estimates and tell you a bit how good / accurate these are. They do not change the estimates and therefore the residuals.